# Get all wordpress users with certain usermeta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin called **Userpro** to give extra meta info to my users. One field in particular, called `business_category` stores a list of categories for each user in an array. The information in the database looks a little like this `a:2:{i:0;s:17:"-Entrepreneurship";i:1;s:11:"-Leadership";}`.

I know that it is possible to query WP users with `get_users( $args );` however since the field I am querying is an array, I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Any help is hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you were in control of how the data is stored, then the obvious suggestion would be to split the information into separate meta keys. However, since that's not the case, we have to use an uglier approach to this problem. I've done this in the past and I'm not happy with it, but sometimes you just have to do it.

Note, that eventually this query might start weighing down your system as the `usermeta` table grows. So eventually you might have to find a way to split this information into separate meta_keys, or just store the `business_category` separately.

```
function get_users_by_business_category( $category ) {
    return get_users( array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'business_category',
                'value'   => gen_sql_like( false, $category ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
    ) );
}

function gen_sql_like( $key = false, $value ) {
    if ( $key ) {
        return str_replace( array( 'a:1:{', '}' ), array( '', '' ), serialize( array( $key => $value ) ) );
    } else {
        return str_replace( array( 'a:1:{i:0;', '}' ), array( '', '' ), serialize( array( $value ) ) );
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
$users = get_users_by_business_category( '-Entrepreneurship' );
```

So what happens here is that we serialize an array that contains our search value - in this case "-Entrepreneurship" and we strip out the beginning and end of the serialized definition of the array. So the `'value'` part of our `meta_query` would be this:

`s:17:"-Entrepreneurship";`

Setting `compare` to `LIKE` will make WordPress add `%` before and after our search value, so it would actually look like this in the final query: `'%s:17:"-Entrepreneurship";%'` and so it would match any records that contain "-Entrepreneurship" in them.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did end up figuring this out yesterday and I came up with something very similar to what you suggested. Although it is good to know that I may have to have a think about not serializing this data to make it better in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2447858 Glad you figured it out! Can you post your solution and mark it as an accepted answer, or mark my answer as accepted? That way this question will no longer be marked as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that did the trick, very similar to what another user posted above.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'business_category',
            'value'   => 'entrepreneurship',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

New fields inside user profile will be saved as meta data. So you need to query using meta_key and meta_value.

Try this,

```
function get_user_by_meta_data( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    // Query for users based on the meta data
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(
        array(
            'meta_key'    =>    $meta_key,
            'meta_value'    =>  $meta_value
        )
    );
    // Get the results from the query, returning the first user
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    if($users){
        return $users[0];   
    }else{
        return false;
    }
} // end get_user_by_meta_data

$getResult = get_user_by_meta_data('business_category', 1); // Example
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that this would work if the meta_value I am trying to find is a simple string. But In the example above, where the meta value is "a:2:{i:0;s:17:"-Entrepreneurship";i:1;s:11:"-Leadership";}." and I want to query all users with meta_key="business_category", meta_value="-entrepreneurship", would this still work since the meta_value is an array?

Comment: Get a user meta using: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta and see if the output is same. If same as you mentioned I can help you to query the data.